# Download a file reading first a file which contains the url

Tags: arrays, file, download, autoit

I have an mp3.txt file which contains URLs to download. How do I read the contents to then download the URLs? I tried this but it's not working:

```
Func _downloader($link)
    Local $dwnarrayread[3] = [IniRead(@ScriptDir & "\mp3.txt", "file_links", "link_1", Default), IniRead(@ScriptDir & "\mp3-2.txt", "file_links", "link_2", Default), IniRead(@ScriptDir & "\mp3-3.txt", "file_links", "link_3", Default)]
    $dwnlink = InetGet($dwnarrayread[$link], @ScriptDir & "PSU-04.mp3", 1, 1)

    Do
        Sleep(50)
        $prc = Round(InetGetInfo($dwnlink, 0) / (InetGetInfo($dwnlink, 1)) * 100)
        GUICtrlSetData($progressbar1, $prc)
    Until InetGetInfo($dwnlink, $INET_DOWNLOADCOMPLETE)
EndFunc
```

mp3.txt file :

```
[files_links]
link_1=https://ftp.psu.ac.th/pub/demo/mp3/PSU-04.mp3
link_2=http://somesite.com/files/file2.zip
link_3=http://somesite.com/files/file3.zip
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> How do I read the contents to then download the URLs?

Example (as per [additional requirement](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/208571-download-a-file-reading-first-a-local-txt-file-which-contains-the-full-url/?do=findComment&comment=1505225)):

```
_Download('mp3.txt', 'files_links', @DesktopDir & '\')

Func _Download(Const $sFileIni, Const $sSection, Const $sDest)
    Local Const $aFile = IniReadSection($sFileIni, $sSection)

    For $i1 = 1 To $aFile[0][0]

        InetGet($aFile[$i1][1], $sDest & StringTrimLeft($aFile[$i1][1], StringInStr($aFile[$i1][1], '/', 0, -1)))

    Next

EndFunc
```

Example as per `GUICtrlSetData()` -attempt:

```
#include <AutoItConstants.au3>
#include <InetConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

_Download('mp3.txt', 'files_links', @DesktopDir & '\')

Func _Download(Const $sFileIni, Const $sSection, Const $sDest)
    Local Const $aFile = IniReadSection($sFileIni, $sSection)
    Local       $aDownload[$aFile[0][0] + 1]

    $aDownload[0] = $aFile[0][0]

    For $i1 = 1 To $aFile[0][0]

        $aDownload[$i1] = InetGet($aFile[$i1][1], $sDest & StringTrimLeft($aFile[$i1][1], StringInStr($aFile[$i1][1], '/', 0, -1)), $INET_FORCERELOAD, $INET_DOWNLOADBACKGROUND)

    Next

    Local Const $iWidth  = 400, _
                $iHeight =  20
    Local $hWnd = GUICreate(@ScriptName, $iWidth, $iHeight * $aDownload[0])
    Local $aHnd[$aDownload[0] + 1]

    For $i1 = 1 To $aDownload[0]

        $aHnd[$i1] = GUICtrlCreateProgress(0, ($i1 - 1) * $iHeight, $iWidth, $iHeight)
        GUICtrlSetTip($aHnd[$i1], $aFile[$i1][1])

    Next

    GUISetState(@SW_SHOW, $hWnd)
    Local $aInfo

    While Not (GUIGetMsg() = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE)

        For $i1 = 1 To $aDownload[0]

            $aInfo = InetGetInfo($aDownload[$i1])
            GUICtrlSetData($aHnd[$i1], ($aInfo[$INET_DOWNLOADCOMPLETE] Or $aInfo[$INET_DOWNLOADSUCCESS]) ? 100 : $aInfo[$INET_DOWNLOADSIZE] / $aInfo[$INET_DOWNLOADREAD])

        Next

        If InetGetInfo() Then ContinueLoop

        MsgBox($MB_OK, @ScriptName, 'No more running downloads.', 0, $hWnd)
        ExitLoop

    WEnd

    For $i1 = 1 To $aDownload[0]

        InetClose($aDownload[$i1])

    Next

EndFunc
```